# Inject configuration files into the injector is it an antipattern?

Tags: design-patterns, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, configuration-management

I'm trying to design a system that inject configuration of each component into each class.

project structure:

```
  |features
   --|component-a
        component-a.service.js
        component-a.config.json
   --|component-b
        component-b.service.js
        component-b.config.json
   --|component-c
        component-c.service.js
        component-c.config.json
```

I think about 2 approaches to inject the config:

1. Create a class config which receives the name of the component
   and locate it, then initialize the attributes from the
   `component-x.config.json` file, and each `component-x`class inherits
   from the class config.
2. Use an injector that locate the configuration file for the
   dependent class when it will be needed for the client.
3. Load the config file for each component and initialize the attributes inside the component constructor explicitly.

Which approach will be better to use with dependency injection pattern?

Answer (score 2):

Approach (1) would couple all your service classes to your dependency injection container which, in my opinion, defeats the purpose. You would like to have services that know nothing about the outside world, they just receive configuration through their constructor/setters.

I think (2) is a better approach. Your services would be self-contained and decoupled from the DI container itself.

You could take a look at how others implement DI [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection#Frameworks). For example, Spring allows using configuration files as you do. Others use annotations to configure their classes.

Comment: More typical for JavaScript, this "injector" would be called a factory object: `ComponentFactory`. Decoupling the dependency injection container from component creation and configuration is definitely desirable in this case.

Comment: @GregBurghardt so should I add the config attributes to each component via the constructor?